# Routing information in email header

Tags: email

How can I Hide "routing header" information such as "return-path" from appearing on email sent/received? This only appeared on email recently so I'm thinking it can be set or cleared by Preference choice, not obvious.  The system is a Mac OSX 10.xx.xx. Snow Leopard.

Comment: **What email client are you using exactly?** Why would you not want to have this information displayed helps not fall to social engineering attacks.

Comment: Migrate to http://apple.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Going to Preference Services there is an drop down menu option to show full header, none, or default.
Default hides the full header (useful only to super users). Hope this helps.
Ruth